# ssl-Authentication can I define a timeout?

Tags: powershell, ssl, connection-timeout

I have this little piece of PS-code to create an ssl-stream to access my email account.
That works fine until today the ssl-server does not respond the authentication and the script hangs at $sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient($server);  waiting for the server's ssl-stream:

```
try {
  $tcpClient = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient
  Write-Host $(Get-Date -format "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss") " starting the Connect..        `r" -NoNewLine
  $tcpClient.Connect($server, 995)
  Write-Host $(Get-Date -format "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss") " ok connected, starting Auth.. `r" -NoNewLine
  if($tcpClient.Connected) {
      [System.Net.Security.SslStream] $sslStream = $tcpClient.GetStream()
      $sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient($server);
      Write-Host $(Get-Date -format "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss") " ok auth.!, starting login ..`r" -NoNewLine
```

Is there a way to to wait only n seconds for the answer of the server and to exit the script with an error-code otherwise?

Comment: It seems this is not possible with connect. You could try with beginconnect()

Comment: @Paul, Thanks, I'll try - but now it works again.